# pgevent.dll can't be deleted because file opened by DHCP Client

Tags: postgresql, window

I am facing an issue with deleting the PostgreSQL install files after uninstalling PostgreSQL 10 from Windows systems. We have automated scripts (as a part of our product) which uninstall postgres and then delete PostgreSQL installation folders from the system.

In order to uninstall Postgres from the system, we call the uninstall-postgresql.exe file (which is created as a part Postgres install) in the following way:

`uninstall-postgresql.exe --mode unattended`

The un-installation completes successfully, however when I try to delete the whole Postgresql install folder, I get an error stating:

[image]

due to this, the uninstall scripts fail because one of the Postgres files can't be deleted. Currently, we reboot the system and then delete all postgres install files.

Can someone help me delete all postgres install files from the system including this pgevent.dll.

Thanks